# Visual Studio 2013 Throwing No Symbols Loaded When Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, debug-symbols

I am getting the following error in Visual Studio 2013 every so often when debugging. This didnt happen in Visual Studio 2012.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the Goth color scheme just confuses you.  See that white rectangle in front of "Microsoft Symbol Servers"?  That's a checkbox, click it.  Then click Load.

Comment: I did, got error message, will post screenshot of that also.  Maybe it will go away now.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the default settings in VS2013 changed slightly (from what I can tell anyway).  Go into Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General.  Scroll down and uncheck "Warn if no symbols on launch (Native only)".  That should stop the message from appearing.